# uncover before pause in beamer later

Tags: beamer, overlays

I have split my frame in two columns. The first column has an  algorithm (interleaved with pause statements). The second column has a figure. 
Currently the figure shows at last (after hitting keys as many times as there are 
pause statements). How can I uncover the figure before any pause statements. 
Attached below is the psuedo code.

```
\begin{columns}[c]
\column{2.00in}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\STATE stmt1
\pause
\STATE stmt2 
\end{algorithmic}
\column{1.00in}
\begin{tikzpicture}
picture code
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you wonder that the figure appears before any statement of the algorithm. In this case, instead of adopting `\pause` you can use very easily the `\visible` command, specifying in which instant of time the object should appear.

For example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usetheme{EastLansing}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}
\begin{columns}[c]
\column{2.00in}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\visible<2->{
\STATE stmt1
}
\visible<3->{
\STATE stmt2 
}
\end{algorithmic}
\column{1.00in}
% appear at first
\visible<1->{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw(0,0)--(1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

will lead to the following frames:

[image: Image appears at first (simply a line)]

Here the image appears at first.

[image: Now also the first statement appears]

Also the first statement appears.

[image: All objects are there: image and algorithm's statements]

All objects are displayed at last.

Comment: Hi Claudio! I am interested in make a beamer presentation using EastLansing theme. Can you help me, please?. I don't know what is happening, you know, I use \usetheme{EastLansing} and I am getting an error saying EastLansing not found. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: @sgmart: Hi! As far as I know the `EastLansing` theme is part of the current version of Beamer, 3.22. Indeed, the beameruserguide version September 19, 2012 shows how to use this theme. I'll recommend you to update your distribution, because this probably fix the problem. Let me know if this solves. `:)`